# Unable to GROUP BY a single field when multiple fields appear in the SELECT clause SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.5

I have a DB table called book. Columns are: id, author, title, isbn, collection_name, collection_id, volume_number, owner_id, can_be_borrowed.
And the owner table includes columns: name, id, address, observations.

*owner_id* is a foreign key that maps to id in owner table.

A collection can appear many times in the book table. For instance there could be 5 copies of the Harry Potter collection. Two of these collections could have *can_be_borrowed=true* while the 3 others could have *can_be_borrowed=false*. Also, collection_id is unique per collection instance. That means each Harry Potter collection would have different collection_id. But they would all have the same collection_name.

So, given an owner_id, I want to find all collections that belong to this owner. The constrains are:

1. For any collection, only volume 1 should be returned
2. Even if a collection appears many times in the DB (like Harry Potter), only one occurrence of volume  1 should be returned
3. If a collection appears many times in the DB, result.can_be_borrowed should be true if one volume across all occurrences of the collections is true. For instance, if only volume 3 of collection 4 in "Harry Potter" set of collections is true, then the result should mean that can_be_borrowed should be true. It doesn't matter what the value of all volumes are.
4. Each result row should include the owner address

Now, please bear with me. My SQL is rusty. Here is what I got sofar:

```
select o.address, o.id, b.*,
       bool_or(can_be_borrowed) 
from owner o, book b 
where b.collection_name in (select collection_name 
                            from owner o2, b2 
                            where o2.id=${owner_id} 
                             and o2.id=b2.id) 
and volume=1 
group by b.collection_name
```

The subquery find all collection_name that belong to provided owner. The outer query search for all volume 1 within the found set of collection_names.
And then to ensure that we get only one item per collection, we group by collection_name. Finally to ensure that we know if the collection can be borrowed, we aggregate on can_be_borrowed.

Now, this query has a problem: I cannot simply group by collection_name. Apparently I have to group by all other columns in the select statement as well. And If I do that, I get a bunch of duplicates and the result is simply not what I want. How can I make this query work?

Comment: You would really benefit from enumerating the possible behaviours by creating a sample set of data.  You can then show the desired results for each corner case you can think of.  Essentially creating a set of unit tests, then using those unit tests as your functional definition.  Like driving development based on tests...  If only I could think of a snappy phrase to encompass such an idea...

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track that this is [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group), but you're not actually restricting your "book" rows, meaning you still have an all-n-per-group situation (`volume=1` is just getting *a* volume, not the "greatest" here).

What is the "greatest" in this case, or even "group"?  Obviously, `can_be_borrowed` is the measure of "greatness", and`collection_name` is our group.

With that, it's fairly easy to write your query:

```
SELECT Owner.id, Owner.address, 
       Borrowable.author, Borrowable.title, Borrowable.isbn, 
       Borrowable.collection_name, Borrowable.collection_id, Borrowable.volume_number, 
       Borrowable.can_be_borrowed
FROM Owner
LEFT JOIN (SELECT owner_id, 
                  author, title, isbn, 
                  collection_name, collection_id, volume_number, can_be_borrowed,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY owner_id, collection_name 
                                    -- Include book_id to make the sort stable
                                    ORDER BY can_be_borrowed DESC NULLS LAST, book_id) as first_borrowable
           FROM Book) AS Borrowable
       ON Borrowable.owner_id = Owner.id
          AND Borrowable.first_borrowable = 1
-- So that all collections belonging to the same owner are together
ORDER BY Owner.owner_id, Borrowable.isbn, Borrowable.collection_name, Borrowable.volume_number, Borrowable.can_be_borrowed
```

Comment: Curious mind: what happens with volume=1 in your query?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, Thanks for replying. One thing you omitted is that I want to capture all fields in the _book_ table.

Comment: @berrytchaks - added all the relevant fields.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Please bear in mine that the _owner_id_ is a parameter that changes. Given a a certain _owner_id_, I want to find all collections that belong to this owner which respect the constraints listed above.

Comment: @berrytchaks - then add that as a host variable, like you were doing with the original statement

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the "group by" as that is not the correct operation for your desired result.

What you want is "**Select DISTINCT ..**." to only get 1 row for each "set".

============== Revised Answer ============================

For this data set:

Owners:

[image]

Books:

[image]

This select does what you want except it returns the actual can_be_borrowed of vol 1, if any volume's can_be_borrowed = 1 (true)

Sample owner=1

```
select o.address, o.id, o.name, b.* 
from owners o, books b 
where o.id=b.owner_id 
and o.id=1  
and b.volume_number=1 
and b.collection_id in (select distinct b2.collection_id    
                        from books b2, owners o2 
                         where b2.owner_id=o2.id and b2.can_be_borrowed=1)
```

result:

[image]

Sample owner=2

```
select o.address, o.id, o.name, b.* 
from owners o, books b 
where o.id=b.owner_id 
and o.id=2 
and b.volume_number=1 
and b.collection_id in (select distinct b2.collection_id 
                        from books b2, owners o2 
                        where b2.owner_id=o2.id 
                          and b2.can_be_borrowed=1)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Uh, no.  There actually is some need for aggregation, given the attempt to find if any book in the collection is borrowable.

Comment: You're dropping rows that can't currently be borrowed, whereas the original query displays yes or no.  That's what needs the aggregation.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  True, I was thinking only the ones that can be borrowed should be returned.  If you want the ones that can not be borrowed, just change to "not in" in the correlated sub-query:
`code`and b.collection_id NOT in (select distinct b2.collection_id 
                        from books b2, owners o2 
                        where b2.owner_id=o2.id 
                          and b2.can_be_borrowed=1) `code` 
If you actually need the full list with a true/false column, you are screwed and must use aggregation.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select O.id ,O.address,B.*,B1.can_be_borrowed
From owner O,book B,(Select collection_id,bool_or(can_be_borrowed)
                 From book
                 Where owner_id=$(owner_id)
                 Group by collection_id
                ) B1
Where B.collection_id=B1.collection_id
  AND B.volume=1
  AND B.owner_id=O.id
```